# Drupal image upload issues

Tags: image, drupal, upload, content-management-system

When uploading images in Drupal I have continuously encounter an issue with the physical size of the image - **not** the size of the file.

Let me explain further. An image could be a small file size (under the restrictions) but be larger than average on the screen. These images fail to upload in Drupal across all sites that I have built using the CMS.

Has this happened for anyone else? Any ideas how I could get around this?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use filefield and imagefield rather than the image module, because I think they give better flexibility.

You could also try imagecache, which gives you a lot of control over the uploaded images

Comment: +1 filefield, imagefield, imagecache is my favorite image combo for Drupal.

Comment: I do use imagechache. I will have a go with the others. Has anyone else experienced this?